# Does Garbage Collector run on Enum type?

Tags: java, enums

According to [*jls § 8.9.2 Enum Body Declarations*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.2)

> It is a compile-time error for an enum declaration to declare a finalizer. An instance of an enum type may never be finalized.

As finalizer executes just before Garbage Collector runs, if finalizer is not present does that means `enum` type always remains loaded in memory, and Garbage Collector is not applicable on `enum` type?

Comment: I believe that the enum itself cannot be collected but weak references in the constant's values can be

Comment: If the enum was collected because there was no reference to it then what would happen if an object was later created that used the enum?

Comment: enums are just normal classes/instances with very little magic - a bit of compiler and a tiny bit of serialization. They extend java.lang.Enum and the compiler adds static final instances for every enum const. But for all practical purposes you can consider them just classes.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you compile an enum like

```
enum Suit {SPADES, HEARTS, CLUBS, DIAMONDS}
```

You will see that the generated bytcodes (i.e. `javap -p Suit`) correspond to a synthetic class:

```
final class Suit extends java.lang.Enum<Suit> {
  public static final Suit SPADES;
  public static final Suit HEARTS;
  public static final Suit CLUBS;
  public static final Suit DIAMONDS;
  private static final Suit[] $VALUES;
  public static Suit[] values();
  public static Suit valueOf(java.lang.String);
  private Suit();
}
```

So, instances of the enum are static members of the class itself. Then I think the only way in which this could be garbage collected would be if the class itself is garbage collected, which is very unlikely to happen if it was loaded by the system class loader.

Comment: it would happen if the `Suite` class itself is unloaded, which does not happen in normal use.

Comment: @assylias I said 'unlikely' and the documentation says 'may never be finalized'. I guess your scenario is possible if the class gets in fact unloaded and if you're a lucky enough that gc runs.

Comment: Mmmm - I don't know to be honest.

Comment: @assylias It may actually be interesting to try, by loading the enum class with a different class loader and then make the class loader garbage collectible. But since the enum cannot have a finalizer, I wonder how could we possible determine if it was gced.

Comment: Indeed - I'm just wondering why an enum would not be finalisable/GC'able since it's just a normal class from a bytecode perspective. But I don't know the definite answer.

Comment: @assylias - A class is never unloaded unless the class loader that loaded it is simultaneously unloaded.  So unless the enum was loaded by a custom class loader it will never, in practice, be unloaded (even though it's conceptually unloadable).

Comment: @HotLick I know that - but in that scenario the jls seems to say that the enums would still not be gc'ed, which is the part i find surprising/am unsure about.

Comment: @assylias - Unless Sun has changed the rules since about Java 4, a class can only be collected when the loading class loader is collected, and when a class loader is collected all classes loaded by that loader must be collected.

Comment: @assylias, the classes loaded by the system classloader CANNOT be GC'd since there is a native ref (gc root) to the system classloader. The latter in effect has a Vector with references to the every single loaded classes (via `Class.forName`). Hence 'unlikely' in the answer is actually 'never'

Answer (score 15):

> Does Garbage Collector run on Enum type?

Just an experiment to show that the enum instances can be made gc eligible.

Define a sample enum as follows -

```
public enum SampleEnum { ONE; }
```

And the test code -

```
Class<SampleEnum> clazz = SampleEnum.class;
String[] fieldNames = {
    "ONE", "ENUM$VALUES"
};
//create a weak reference to the instance
WeakReference<SampleEnum> ref = new WeakReference<SampleEnum>(SampleEnum.ONE);
//remove the hard references
for (String fieldName: fieldNames) {
    Field feld = clazz.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
    Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
    modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
    modifiersField.setInt(feld, feld.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
    feld.setAccessible(true);
    feld.set(null, null);
}
//wait until a gc occurs and clears the weak ref
while (ref.get() != null) {
    System.out.println("Waiting ...");
    System.gc();
}
//output just to verify that the weak ref is cleared by the gc
System.out.println("Weak reference is cleared!");
```

Try it with the `-verbose:gc` option.

---

> As finalizer executes just before Garbage Collector runs, if finalizer is not present does that means enum type always remains loaded in memory, and Garbage Collector is not applicable on enum type?

Actually the presence/absence of finalizer does not have anything to do with whether or not any object will be gc'ed. The enum instances are not gc'ed because they are referred to by the static fields within the enum class generated by the compiler.

Comment: Reflection can break some language guarantees. "XYZ is possible with unsafe use of reflection" isn't much more useful than "XYZ is possible with sun.misc.Unsafe" or "XYZ is possible with JNI and unsafe use of pointers".

Comment: @immibis: There are 2 messages that I wanted the OP to take away from this answer - 1) There is nothing that tells the GC to not run on the enum instances and 2) It's not the absence of finalizer that keeps those instances from being gc'ed.
English is my 2nd language so I think I failed to deliver the message properly. Please feel free to edit the answer.

Comment: No, that makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that since enum's and enum types are always static it would behave as if it were a static member since it could be accessed at any time.

Additionally finalizers are designed to be invoked when an Object is unloaded from memory as they are intended to perform any necessary cleanup operation and you can't make objects of Enum's.

Comment: An enum is not a class.  Enum is one of the 5 types of the CTS.  But I agree with your answer on static (just not static object).

Answer (score 4):

It's a curious couple of sentences.

> It is a compile-time error for an enum declaration to declare a finalizer.

That's clear enough.  I don't know why that would be the case, but the rules are the rules.  This also appears to be enforced by the fact that enums derive from `Enum`, and the API spec says that `Enum` has a `final` finalizer.

> An instance of an enum type may never be finalized.

The language here seems ambiguous to me.  Are they declaring that no instance of an enum type will ever be finalized?  If so, why "may"?  Why not just say so?  Are they just reminding us that finalization isn't guaranteed to occur?  Either way, it doesn't matter....

`Object`'s `finalize` method is defined to do nothing ([12.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6)).  `Enum` derives from `Object`, and enums derive from `Enum`.  `Enum`'s finalizer isn't defined to do anything, and you can't override it, so when you put it all together *the finalization of an enum instance has no effects.*

In my interpretation, the enum instances can be garbage collected (although as others have pointed out the circumstances that allow this to happen are a bit unusual), and as their `finalize` method is defined not to do anything, whether or not the `finalize` method is ever called is a moot point.

Comment: One should remember in all this that Enum is largely a compiler fiction and that there is nothing in the JVM itself that specifically supports Enum.

Comment: @HotLicks, the JVM specification lists some flags in the classfile format that identify enums, but I'm not sure why or if the JVM actually uses them for anything.