# why default serialization is prevented in enum class

Tags: java, serialization, enums

I have been searching web to find the answers of some of the queries related to enum class in java.

My query is why default De-serialization has been prevented in enum class. I can see that the enum class implements Serializable interface but it also have 2 methods as below --

```
 private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException,
    ClassNotFoundException {
    throw new InvalidObjectException("can't deserialize enum");
}

private void readObjectNoData() throws ObjectStreamException {
    throw new InvalidObjectException("can't deserialize enum");
}
```

I am more confused after seeing this class. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I am more confused since ENUM implements serializable interface itself and have above methods too that throws "throw new InvalidObjectException("can't deserialize enum");" Exception. so i am not getting clear understanding of what above two methods are for ?

Also comments on above two methods says "prevent default deserialization" what does it mean ?

Comment: Not a Duplicate please check edits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enumeration values are serializable -- and that's all that is claimed by implementing the `Serializable` interface.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Dummy {

    public enum Color {
        RED, GREEN, BLUE
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        System.out.println(deserialize(serialize(Color.GREEN), Color.class));
    }

    private static <T> T deserialize(byte[] data, Class<T> cls) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

        try (final ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
             final ObjectInputStream reader = new ObjectInputStream(stream)) {

            return cls.cast(reader.readObject());
        }
    }

    private static byte[] serialize(Serializable obj) throws IOException {

        final ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try {

            try (final ObjectOutputStream writer = new ObjectOutputStream(stream)) {

                writer.writeObject(obj);
            }

        } finally {

            stream.close();
        }

        return stream.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

However, due to the special nature of enumeration constants, the run-time cannot use the default serialization mechanism, as that would allow the construction of multiple values of a given constant, violating the guarantee, that enumeration constants are singletons.

For this reason, the run-time uses a "non-default" mechanism to serialize/deserialize enumeration constants, which ensures the singleton property. Disarming the default mechanism by overriding `readObject` is simply a security measure, which makes sure, that you cannot trick the VM into creating new constants by having it deserialize a maliciously hacked byte stream.

*TL;DR* Enumeration constants are perfectly (de)serializable as claimed by having the base class `Enum` implement the `Serializable` interface. However, internally, the VM/run-time handles the serialization specially, and disables the default mechanism for these kinds of objects.

Answer (score 2):

Simple because in Java `enum` is singleton in JVM, and `deserialize()` would create another instance thus break the singleton contract.

Comment: It means we can serialize Enum but cant deserialize it ?

Comment: Since `deserialize()` is blocked you cannot use the default way to transfer `enum` objects i.e. serialize `enum` objects, hoping they could be deserialized in another JVM correctly. A common way is to use the `cardinal()` value.